# difference between ISO_8859_1 and latin1

Tags: java, encoding

difference between ISO_8859_1 and latin1 ??  also what is the difference between ASCII and US_ASCII ??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `latin 1` is also called `ISO-8859-1` as you can see [here](http://casa.colorado.edu/~ajsh/iso8859-1.html). And `ASCII` is also called `US-ASCII` so they are also the same character encoding as you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).